# Can I cache an API call object using Vue JS lifecycle hooks?

Tags: vue.js, logic, lifecycle

I'm using The Strain API which has a search query that gets all the strains in its database. It says to use this sparingly as it requires a lot of computing power. My question is: can I call it once in the App component life cycle hook, save the response in the App data(), and cache it somehow so that if the data.object.length != 0, it doesn't try calling it again? Then I could pass it as a prop to any other component that needs it. Sorry, new to VueJs and programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best thing in my opinion is to keep the calculated data in a service, so that you in your mounted component simply call the getData (), imported from the StrainService.js

```
// StrainService.js
let response = null;


const getData = async () => {
    if (!response) {
        response = await StrainApiCall()
    }

    return response
}


const StrainApiCall = () => {
    return axios.get('yourdata.com') // your api call
}


export {
    getData
}
```